# Show overlay on hover, but tap to remove overlay on mobile devices

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation menu on my website. The menu is largely controlled with CSS, except for an overlay which uses jQuery. When the user hovers over the menu item, an overlay is displayed across the entire page to darken it and to allow the menu to be seen more clearly against it. This works well on desktops, but on mobile devices the overlay never disappears once it is activated and this prevents users clicking on anything on the site. Here is my code:

**jQuery**

```
jQuery( "#meganav" ).on("mouseenter",
    function() {
    jQuery("#meganav-overlay").addClass("meganav-overlay").css({opacity: 0.2}).show();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
jQuery("#meganav-overlay").removeClass("meganav-overlay").hide();    
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="meganav-overlay"></div>
```

I thought the most natural way to overcome this issue would be to close the overlay if the user taps on it (i.e. if they tap anywhere on the screen except the menu). Is anyone able to help me achieve this? Alternatively, is there a better way to code the above?

Many thanks,

Katie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need jQuery for hover effects, it can be applied to `<div>` directly with CSS but I guess you knew this, see demo:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9V8e/1161/)**

---

But, in order to make a hover effect with a `.click()` function to remove the opacity on `mouseenter, mouseleave`, you could use something like this - see demo:

**[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ4M7/15/)**